# 1 запрос для 2х переменных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся Бренды и их id – «Brands» @например@ (drand_id - 1, brand - KIA)
Есть вторая таблица с товарами, в которую должны попадать эти значения. «Products» (…brand_id,brand…)
Сейчас для попадания значений из одной таблицы в другую, я использую 2 запроса, один для brand другой для brand_id. (Это не удобно)
Можно ли сделать, чтоб одним запросом значения попадали каждое в свою ячейку? 
Нужно чтоб в select было указано 2 name: form_brand и form_brand_id

Вот пример одного запроса, второй такой же

```
    <select name="form_brand" id="type" size="1" >
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT brand FROM brands ORDER BY brand ASC",$link);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        do
        {
           echo '
            <li>
            <option value="'.$row{"brand"}.'" >'.$row{"brand"}.'</option>
            </li>
            ';
            }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));   
   }        
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Хранить __название бренда__ в таблице продуктов не надо, достаточно привязки к ИД бренда. Представьте что бренд переименовали и что вы будете делать? Обновлять все записи в таблице продуктов? В вашем случае в `value` аттрибуте `option` требуется выводить `id` бренда, соответственно требуется модифицировать sql-запрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А как потом при выводе сопоставить id бренда с брендом, чтоб в карточке товара вывелся бренд а не его id?

Comment: Для этого надо либо делать допзапрос за именем бренда либо использовать в первом запросе `JOIN`, второй метод предпочтительней.

Comment: У вас цикл неверный. Нужно брать просто `while`. А к теме вашего вопроса, вам нужно выполнять один и `SELECT * FROM brands ...`